# Can I create a Parallels Virtual Machine instance from an existing PC?

Tags: windows-7, macos, virtual-machine, parallels

I have a laptop running Windows 7 Pro where I am not the admin. (The company did the setup and gave me the machine) I also have my personal laptop that is a Macbook Pro and I have Parallels installed.

Is there anyway I can clone the whole operating system from the Windows machine and create a new Virtual instance that will run on Parallels, so I do not have to be stuck with the terrible machine the company gave me but I also do not need to go to IT to explain myself?

Comment: Any tool that can create a VM from physical hardware, can’t be installed, as a normal user.

Comment: You need to be able to install the Transporter onto the PC. If you're not admin you won't be able to do that. https://kb.parallels.com/en/123929